# Bootstrap4 Form Example is Rendering Incorrectly

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to build a simple email form like in the [Bootstrap 4 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-controls) but for some reason the formatting is wrong.

This is what the example looks like:
[image]

But for some reason this is what it compiles to in my project:
[image]

Clearly there's something in my codebase/environment that's messing with the layout. Why are my fields not in separate rows like the example? Why is there no spacing between elements? Why is the submit button not blue? It's a mess. Is my bootstrap 4 dependency not installed properly?

I'm using the exact html from the example. Code below.

```
<template>
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
      <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

main.ts

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

// @ts-ignore
createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
```

Comment: You may need to import the CSS into your project.  Can you show your *main.js*?  Also check out [BoostrapVue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/) if you're not already using it

Comment: Updated my post with my main.ts file. I'm looking into BootstrapVue now

Comment: For now, add to *main.js*:  `import 'bootstrap';` and `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

Comment: Ah, that worked, but also broke other parts of my webpage. I guess I wasn't importing bootstrap correctly

Comment: There are 2 imports, make sure you use both.  You also need both for `BootstrapVue` if you decide to use that.

Comment: Yep, I installed BootstrapVue before testing. This did fix the original issue, it looks like the other parts of my UI that are wonky are simply in need of new styling now that my bootstrap directives are actually working

Comment: @Dan Quite interesting, the typical import code for your `main.ts` file to include Bootstrap4.5 in your project indeed doesn't work for Vue3, you have to use the 2 imports you shared specifically instead of what the bootstrap-vue.org docs indicate. Apparently the Bootstrap team is aiming to support Vue3 via Bootstrap5 by the end of 2020. https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/5196

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are looking for a simple solution for a static website or basic stuff
all you need to do is to add this cdn to your html

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

and this bootstrap javascript cdn for dropdowns and navbar

```
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and the jQuery cdn

check this link for a live preview

https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-ss4nvu?file=script.js

basicly this

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

at the head tag :)

but i see that you mentioned vue js in the tags you are looking for an answer so i also recommend on going throw the website of vueJS bootstrap which is amazing if you have any trouble i am available also in gmail :)

dolev146@gmail.com

Comment: Do I still need to add cdn's to my HTML headers if i'm using npm install?

Comment: if you need a quick and dirty solution then find the HTML files in your vue app and paste the code above like what i did here https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-hajqhh?file=public%2Findex.html

Comment: what up if you want a good practice you will have to go and read this website no other option https://bootstrap-vue.org/ bootstrap that is specifically built for vue

Comment: FYI it seems that Bootstrap 4.5 doesn't work with Vue3 yet (which is unfortunately what i'm using) . https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/5196

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to link css files from bootstrap.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

copy paste it in the head of your html

also read the get started documentation: [bootstrap get started doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)